# Duplicate App to an already existing ID on Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blogs

I made a blog  in Python and I am running it off of Google App Engine. When I started, I put a random ID, just because I was experimenting. Lately, my blog got a bit popular and I wanted to change the ID. I wanted to duplicate my app, but the problem is that I already registered that ID a while ago with google. How can I duplicate it even though the name already exists.

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading

Note: Application IDs must begin with a letter. **Once you register an application ID, you can delete it, but you can't re-register that same application ID after it has been deleted**. You can skip these next steps if you don't want to register an ID at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You say you already used that id before.
If you havent deleted that app just use that one to load your new code there. You will need to delete existing datastore data etc.